# Is there any method to create a new object of different sub-class when a button is pressed and then put it inside dragHandler?

Tags: java, javafx, polymorphism

I don't know if I am asking the right question. I am creating a paint-like application in which the user selects a shape and then draws it on the canvas with mouse drag. I have created a superclass GeometricObject and the sub-classes Line, Rectangle and Eclipse extend it. I declared a variable "go" of type GeometricObject. Based on which button is pressed, a new object of a different sub-class is created and stored in go. For example, if Eclipse button is pressed, a new object of type Eclipse is created and so on. In the dragHandler, if go variable stores a reference to object of type Eclipse, then go is casted to type eclipse and draw method of eclipse is called. But in my case this logic does not work.

```java
GeometricObject go;
public void dragHandler(MouseEvent mouseEvent){

/// transgc is graphicsContext2D

        transgc.clearRect(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight);
        ex=mouseEvent.getX();
        ey=mouseEvent.getY();

        GeometricObject go=new Rectangle(sx,sy,ex,ey,colorPicker.getValue());

        if(go instanceof Lines)
            ((Lines)go).draw(transgc);
        else if(go instanceof Eclipse)
            ((Eclipse)go).draw(transgc);
        else if(go instanceof Rectangle)
            ((Rectangle)go).draw(transgc);

}

 public void eclipseHandler(ActionEvent e){
        go=new Eclipse(sx,sy,ex,ey,colorPicker.getValue());
    }
    public void rectangleHandler(ActionEvent e){
        go=new Rectangle(sx,sy,ex,ey,colorPicker.getValue());
    }

    public void linesHandler(ActionEvent e){
        go=new Lines(sx,sy,ex,ey,colorPicker.getValue());
    }
```

Expected output - different shape is drawn when different button is pressed and then mouse is dragged

Actual output - nothing is getting drawn while the mouse is dragged

Comment: Why do you cast? This is not how you use polymorphism.

You should simply call `go.draw()` on your object without if and without casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GeometricObject go=new Rectangle(sx,sy,ex,ey,colorPicker.getValue());

        if(go instanceof Lines)
            ((Lines)go).draw(transgc);
        else if(go instanceof Eclipse)
            ((Eclipse)go).draw(transgc);
        else if(go instanceof Rectangle)
            ((Rectangle)go).draw(transgc);
```

Here you are always creating a **Rectangle** object 'go'. It should be omitted.